# How to access /etc/ldap/slapd.conf file?

Tags: ldap

I have to configure /etc/ldap/slapd.conf in Ubuntu 12.04. However, on installing slapd, I do not get the slapd.conf file. Instead I am getting the /etc/ldap/slapd.d directory, which has files such as cn=config in it.

How do I get access to the slapd.conf file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either, create it yourself (when you save the file any text editor will create it if it do not exist already) or you can add the configuration in the `slapd.d` directory. Any of them will do.